# Share Python ChatBot with other users

Tags: python, chatbot

I have followed a few articles online and was able to create my own chat bot within Python, but it's not super helpful to me because I inpputed all of the information into the tool so I know it already. The real value would be for me to be able to share the chatbot so others can access it and get these same answers.

What is the easiest way to share this chat bot freely and securely without forcing users to install Python on their laptop?

Comment: Have you tried using an online IDE? I strongly recommend repl.it. This allows you to share code via link. The problem is that other people could view the source, unless you happen to buy a "Hacker Plan" around $8/month (I don't know for sure). If that's fine with you, than I would definitely upload your code to it, then share the code with others via link. https://repl.it/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/).
From the website:

> PyInstaller freezes (packages) Python applications into stand-alone executables, under Windows, GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris and AIX.

So by using it, your users will not need to install Python.